# What do you call something that reads and writes files?

Tags: programming, technical, computing, technology

In programming, it's common to write a class that both reads and writes files. What do you call this type of thing? Is it a file handler? A file parser? A file provider? A file streamer? How about a filer? Or do you just call it a file reader and leave it at that?

Comment: If you're going to downvote, at least leave a helpful reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first response is probably the best, along with file **processor**.

> processor: a machine that processes something.
>
> process: a series of actions or steps taken in order to achieve a particular end.

A **parser** implies that it only reads the files, not writes them.

A **provider** implies it is the source of the file, not an intermediary.

A **streamer** implies the files are either being written continually or converted continually.

A **filer** implies that the files are stored without modification.

A **reader** implies the files are read without modification.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing after I asked the question: what does it do? It handles file operations. File handler it is. (Processor is too long!)

Comment: _Processor is too long!_ - careful, it's that kind of thinking that gave us the Y2K bug! ;)

Comment: @Koveras "File Handler" is *very* close to the term "File Handle" - which is what you call a unique identifier after a **process** has opened a file. I wouldn't recommend use of "Handler" as it'd be easy for a tech-savvy reader to confuse the two.

Comment: @Doc how about "file do-er?" It does things with files.

Comment: @Koveras "Do-er" is very vague and unprofessional. What does it do to the files; take them for a walk? Throw them a birthday party? (May I ask why **Processor** is too long?)

Comment: I was kidding :p

Comment: @Koveras The day I am able to detect sarcasm on the internet is the day pigs fly. Still, was there a reason **Processor** was too long for you to use? Do you need the word to be a certain length?

Comment: I was kidding about that too. Point taken: FileHandler is too similar to FileHandle. FileProcessor works just fine.